# copying HashMap class is giving error

Tags: java, netbeans, hashmap

I am trying to understand working of class HashMap . I copied it's source code in netbeans but am getting a compile time error related to the TreeNode interface and some other non initialisation errors .

First error : Inside putval() method :

```
 ..
 else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
            e = ((TreeNode<K,V>)p).putTreeVal(this, tab, hash, key, 
 value);
 ..
```

it says Node cannot be converted to TreeNode .

Other error is coming in resize() method . And there are many more errors .

Am I doing it the wrong way or have I missed something in my code . Please help.

Comment: It's not a good idea to copy the source code of any Java's `Collection` class and creating your own out of it just to learn its behavior. Instead it is always recommended to run through the source code using debugger.

Comment: Why it's not a good idea ?

Comment: Any Java APIs that you use, may internally use some native methods or some internal dependencies/classes which you may not have access to. So if you want to test any Java's own API, it's always preferred to create a client program that uses that API and then, you can debug your client code line by line to understand the functionality of the API in which you are interested.